# Energy of a sinc signal

Tags: fourier-transform, fourier, fourier-series

My book give me two signals to demonstrate that the temporal translation does not alter the energy and area. It gave me

$$ x(t)=\operatorname{sinc}(t) $$

and

$$ s(t)=x(t-T)$$

and I found that energy ( with rayleigh theorem ) and area are 1 for $x(t)$. For $s(t)$ I found an area=1 but now , with Rayleigh I should demonstrate that.

$$  \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} | \operatorname{rect}(f) \,e^{- i 2 \pi f T } |^{2} \ \mathrm{d}f  $$

As I made for $x(t)$,

$$ \operatorname{rect}(t) = |\operatorname{rect}(t)|^{2} $$

but solving the last integral this didn’t give me 1. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: i might suggest explicitly defining your two functions $\operatorname{rect}(\cdot)$ and $\operatorname{sinc}(\cdot)$.

Comment: This helps me , I wrote $$ e^{-i 2 \pi f T} $$ as $$ cos ( 2 \pi f T ) - i sen ( 2 \pi f T) $$. So in this terms $$ | e^{-i 2 \pi f T } | = 1 $$ so now I obtain an integer of 1

Comment: i can't edit your comments (i **can** edit your question).  try using a backslash before "sin" or "cos" or "log" or whatever function and $\LaTeX$ will show it as a function.  the functions $\operatorname{rect}$ and $\operatorname{sinc}$ don't seem to be in LaTeX's list of known functions so you need to use "\operatorname{rect}".

Comment: You have an issue solving the last integral, How did you go about solving it?

Comment: $$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} 1 dt = [t]_ {-\infty}^{+\infty} $$  it’s the only thing in obtained 

Comment: whoa whoa whoa, where did that come from? I thought we were integrating $|\text{rect}(t)|^2$?

Comment: My suggestion is to just "crank" the integral by stepping through it. Write it down in general terms, massage the integrand (it is constant so it just insert that as you have), and lastly check your limits when you do this otherwise you won't be doing the integral you're trying to compute

Comment: ops... I’m an idiot ! I cancelled completely rect function